# How to set up an alternate DNS server for AWS's China EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

Currently, the DNS server for the EC2 instance in AWS China is 10.0.0.2, as shown below:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-191 ec2-user]# cat /etc/resolv.conf 

search cn-north-1.compute.internal

nameserver 10.0.0.2
```

If the DNS server is down, the domain name of the EC2 instance will not be resolved. Is there any way to create an alternate DNS server or a slave DNS server to avoid this problem?

What are the solutions for the following two environments:

1. I have several EC2 instances running in the AWS US region. So, can I set up a DNS server in the US as an alternate DNS server for the EC2 instance in China? If this method works, what are the specific steps? What services need to be connected through the AWS network in China and the US?
2. I only have instances of the AWS China region, and there are no instances of other areas of AWS. How can I accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0):

There is no apparent problem to solved, here.

First, this IP address does not represent a single DNS server.

The [Amazon DNS Server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html#AmazonDNS) is actually a service of provided by the network infrastructure -- not a dedicated machine.

Anything can theoretically fail, but a failure of this subsystem is unlikely unless the physical hardware where this VM is running or its hypervisor has failed or is failing... in which case, the server will fail its health checks and will be offline.

Second, this isn't quite accurate:

> *If the DNS server is down, the domain name of the EC2 instance will not be resolved*

If the VPC DNS resolver service were to somehow fail, this would prevent the instance from resolving any names, but names *pointing to* the instance are not something this server does.  This server is only used when the instance is doing the lookup -- not when something else is looking up the instance.